# Error when applying a function to sapply in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply, sapply

I am trying to use an existing external function to update a column in my dataframe. The function computes values fine independently, and I have checked that the df is correctly filled with the values before applying the function using sapply. Maybe I should be using lapply (also doesn't work).  I receive the following error: *function*(....) is not a function, character or symbol.

I have pasted my code - its long because there are 3 functions that are imbedded in the one I'm trying to use for this (pasted at end). I'm pretty new to apply family so I'm guessing this is a simple problem....

```
cvVals <- seq(0.1,2,length.out=10)
mVals <- seq(1,2,length.out=10)
zpVals <- seq(0.001,0.10,length.out=10)
rpVals<-0

#iterate through time (up to 5000 yrs)
imax<-5000

#fill a matrix with each combination of cv, m, q values
newdf <- data.frame(expand.grid(cv=cvVals, m=mVals, zp=zpVals,rp=rpVals))

#I want to put the result from Tlalt into the rp column for each combination of Cv,m,zp
rps<-sapply(newdf,T1alt(newdf$zp,newdf$cv,newdf$m,imax))

#this looks wrong
df$rp<-rps
```

#### functions needed to run this code

```
p <- function(zp, Cv, M, t) {
  p_exceed <- pnorm(qnorm(zp,lower.tail=FALSE) * sigma_y(Cv), beta(M) * t, sigma_y(Cv),lower.tail=FALSE)
  return (p_exceed)
}
sigma_y <- function(Cv) {
      stdev_y <- sqrt(log(1+Cv^2))
      return (stdev_y)
}
beta <- function(M) {
  b_slope <- log(M) / 10
  return (b_slope)
}

T1alt <- function(zp,Cv,M,tmax){
 A<-0 
 for (i in 1:tmax) {

    q_t <- prod(1 - p(zp, Cv, M, seq(1:(i-1))))
    A = A + q_t
  }
  nonstatT<-1+A
  return(nonstatT)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `newdf$rp <- Vectorize(T1alt)(newdf$zp,newdf$cv,newdf$m,imax)` or `newdf$rp2 <- mapply(T1alt,newdf$zp,newdf$cv,newdf$m,imax)`?

Comment: I just tried the Vectorize version and it works great! Thank you thank you